# How to crop a image and save?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, crop

I have opened a image in a `QHBoxLayout`. I need to crop the opened image and save the cropped image. How I can do this in PySide?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("re.png")

        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)


        self.rect = QtCore.QRect()


        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Open Image')
        self.show()   
        # Tried here to implement Qpen      
        #self.painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)    
        #self.painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine));
        #self.painter.drawRect(self.rect);
def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is it important for the croping that you show it in a QHBoxLayout? Do you maybe also want to specify the cropping region by QRubberBand?

Comment: No it is not important to show cropping in `QHBoxLayout` . I just wanted to show the image in a layout and crop and save. How to use ` QRubberBand` ?

Comment: If it is not important than in principle you don't need to show any of the code you have shown. It would make the question shorter, easier to understand and better. But if you want the user to select a cropping region then I advice you to use a QRubberBand. I haven't found any good examples. But the documentation should help already or asking a question here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest use class [`QtGui.QRubberBand`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qrubberband.html) to select area of image to crop. (PySide also implements the same functionality as PyQt)

First, implement method `mouseMoveEvent (self, QMouseEvent)`, `mouseReleaseEvent (self, QMouseEvent)` and `mousePressEvent (self, QMouseEvent)` (More infomation read in `QtGui.QRubberBand` class reference).

Next, get last geometry of `QtGui.QRubberBand` to crop image by use [`QRect QWidget.geometry (self)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#geometry).

Last, Use [`QPixmap QPixmap.copy (self, QRect rect = QRect())`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpixmap.html#copy) to crop image by put geometry from crop area. And save image it by use [`bool QPixmap.save (self, QString fileName, str format = None, int quality = -1)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpixmap.html#save).

Example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class QExampleLabel (QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QExampleLabel, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI (self):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('input.png'))

    def mousePressEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.originQPoint = eventQMouseEvent.pos()
        self.currentQRubberBand = QtGui.QRubberBand(QtGui.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint, QtCore.QSize()))
        self.currentQRubberBand.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint, eventQMouseEvent.pos()).normalized())

    def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.currentQRubberBand.hide()
        currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()
        self.currentQRubberBand.deleteLater()
        cropQPixmap = self.pixmap().copy(currentQRect)
        cropQPixmap.save('output.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQExampleLabel = QExampleLabel()
    myQExampleLabel.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use QImage's `copy` method:

```
im2 = im.copy(self.rect)
im2.save(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore,QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QRubberBand, QLabel, QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect


class QExampleLabel (QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QExampleLabel, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI (self):
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap('input.png'))

    def mousePressEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.originQPoint = eventQMouseEvent.pos()
        self.currentQRubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, QtCore.QSize()))
        self.currentQRubberBand.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, eventQMouseEvent.pos()).normalized())

    def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.currentQRubberBand.hide()
        currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()
        self.currentQRubberBand.deleteLater()
        cropQPixmap = self.pixmap().copy(currentQRect)
        cropQPixmap.save('output.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQExampleLabel = QExampleLabel()
    myQExampleLabel.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: This answer does not explain why it works, how can one learn from it?