# How to make paintEvent work when subclassing QRubberBand?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyside

Currently, I'm using PySide to do image cropping under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I came across the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25806393/522000) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795380/how-to-crop-a-image-and-save), which describes a rough idea of how to do image cropping. Now I'd like to change the width and color of the cropping rectangle. Following [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/21324-How-to-draw-QRubberBand-with-red-color), I understand I should create a class which subclasses `QRubberBand` and overrides the `paintEvent` method. So I got the `python` code at the bottom. As you can see, I did `pen.setWidth(5)` in `paintEvent`. However, when I do image cropping, the line width does not change (seems to remain `1` as default). See the following red rectangle.

Please help. Thanks!

[image]

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyRubberBand(QtGui.QRubberBand):
    def __init__(self, QRubberBand_Shape, QWidget_parent=None):
        super(MyRubberBand, self).__init__(QRubberBand_Shape, QWidget_parent)
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red))
        self.setPalette(palette)

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        # painter.begin(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        # pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        # pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red))
        pen.setWidth(5)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        option = QtGui.QStyleOptionFocusRect()
        option.initFrom(self)
        painter.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_FocusFrame, option)

class QExampleLabel (QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QExampleLabel, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI (self):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('images/3.png'))
        self.currentQRubberBand = MyRubberBand(QtGui.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def mousePressEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        print 'mouse pressed'
        self.originQPoint = eventQMouseEvent.pos()
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint, QtCore.QSize()))
        self.currentQRubberBand.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint, eventQMouseEvent.pos()).normalized())

    def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        print 'mouse released'
        # self.currentQRubberBand.hide()
        currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()
        # self.currentQRubberBand.deleteLater()
        cropQPixmap = self.pixmap().copy(currentQRect)
        cropQPixmap.save('output.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQExampleLabel = QExampleLabel()
    myQExampleLabel.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I was recently trying to do the same thing and seen this so I want to post some code for anyone else who might come across this as well.

Your code with updated `paintEvent`.

PySide2:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QSize
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QPen, QBrush, QPixmap, QPainter, QPalette
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QRubberBand

class MyRubberBand(QRubberBand):
    def __init__(self, QRubberBand_Shape, QWidget_parent=None):
        super(MyRubberBand, self).__init__(QRubberBand_Shape, QWidget_parent)
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.WindowText, QBrush(Qt.red))
        self.setPalette(palette)

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        ###QRubberBand with black border and transparent background###
        painter = QPainter(self)
        ###Border Color with width set at 6###
        pen_color = QColor(0, 0, 0, 255)
        painter.setPen(QPen(pen_color, 6))
        ###Transparent background###
        brush_color = QColor(Qt.transparent)
        ###Or to use solid background color###
        # brush_color = QColor(Qt.red)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(brush_color))
        painter.drawRect(QPaintEvent.rect())

class QExampleLabel (QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QExampleLabel, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI (self):
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/3.png'))
        self.currentQRubberBand = MyRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def mousePressEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        print('mouse pressed')
        self.originQPoint = eventQMouseEvent.pos()
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, QSize()))
        self.currentQRubberBand.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, eventQMouseEvent.pos()).normalized())

    def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        print('mouse released')
        # self.currentQRubberBand.hide()
        currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()
        # self.currentQRubberBand.deleteLater()
        cropQPixmap = self.pixmap().copy(currentQRect)
        cropQPixmap.save('output.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQExampleLabel = QExampleLabel()
    myQExampleLabel.resize(800, 600)
    myQExampleLabel.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPen, QBrush, QPixmap, QPainter, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QRubberBand

class MyRubberBand(QRubberBand):
    def __init__(self, QRubberBand_Shape, QWidget_parent=None):
        super(MyRubberBand, self).__init__(QRubberBand_Shape, QWidget_parent)
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.WindowText, QBrush(Qt.red))
        self.setPalette(palette)

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        ###QRubberBand with black border and transparent background###
        painter = QPainter(self)
        ###Border Color with width set at 6###
        pen_color = QColor(0, 0, 0, 255)
        painter.setPen(QPen(pen_color, 6))
        ###Transparent background###
        brush_color = QColor(Qt.transparent)
        ###Or to use solid background color###
        # brush_color = QColor(Qt.red)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(brush_color))
        painter.drawRect(QPaintEvent.rect())

class QExampleLabel (QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QExampleLabel, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI (self):
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/3.png'))
        self.currentQRubberBand = MyRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def mousePressEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        print('mouse pressed')
        self.originQPoint = eventQMouseEvent.pos()
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, QSize()))
        self.currentQRubberBand.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, eventQMouseEvent.pos()).normalized())

    def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        print('mouse released')
        # self.currentQRubberBand.hide()
        currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()
        # self.currentQRubberBand.deleteLater()
        cropQPixmap = self.pixmap().copy(currentQRect)
        cropQPixmap.save('output.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQExampleLabel = QExampleLabel()
    myQExampleLabel.resize(800, 600)
    myQExampleLabel.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```